# how to take objects from collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the collection with few objects

but when I write

```
db.collection("girlTypes").find()
```

I catch error

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
at stringify (C:\rater\rater\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1119:12)
at ServerResponse.json (C:\rater\rater\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:260:14)
at ServerResponse.send (C:\rater\rater\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:158:21)
at app.get (C:\rater\rater\server\src\app.js:265:17)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\rater\rater\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\rater\rater\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at complete (C:\rater\rater\server\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:263:13)
at C:\rater\rater\server\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:270:15
at pass (C:\rater\rater\server\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:431:14)
at Authenticator.transformAuthInfo (C:\rater\rater\server\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:453:5)
at C:\rater\rater\server\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:267:22
at C:\rater\rater\server\node_modules\passport\lib\http\request.js:52:7
at C:\rater\rater\server\node_modules\passport\lib\sessionmanager.js:26:5
at pass (C:\rater\rater\server\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:277:43)
at serialized (C:\rater\rater\server\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:286:7)
```

And the get cursor

In tutorials, all authors say that this command should return me list of objects
What I miss? maybe some modules? Because when I use

> find 
>   command with models everything is ok.

Comment: Can you post whole code?

Answer (score 0):

If find answer

```
   db.collection("girlTypes").find({}).toArray(function(error, girlType)
```